# Is there a way to continue playing the 2018 Google Halloween game?

Tags: google-doodles

For a few days leading up to Halloween in 2018, Google had a multiplayer minigame up as its Google Doodle on the search site. Now that Halloween is over, is there a place I can go to keep on playing the game?

Also, is there a way to set up my own server for the game so that if Google ever kills the game's servers, I can still host a game with friends?

Comment: The minigame from 2016, a 20-minute single-player action game, is still available here: https://www.google.com/doodles/halloween-2016

Comment: Follow-up question: is there any way to play the game **full size**? The archived version is teeny-tiny.

Comment: Finally seems to be down as of the week of 13th May 2019 - seemed like the most relevant place to post this for a google search.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Google keeps an archive of past Doodles on their website: https://www.google.com/doodles

It should be possible to play the [Halloween 2018](https://www.google.com/doodles/halloween-2018) doodle from there. And I don't think they will ever take it down, since Google keeps an archive going back years.

Comment: Never say never when it comes to Google sunsetting their own products.

Answer (score 9):

The game is still available in Google's Doodle archives: https://www.google.com/doodles/halloween-2018

When the game is starting, there's an option to "Host a Game," so that might work for spinning up your own server for friends.

Answer (score 0):

Although it worked yesterday from the archive, it seems to be totally not allowing game play now. Although it allows you to select Host Game, and allows those you invite to connect, it then hangs on "Connecting..." with the Hosted Game option, or on "Waiting for Players" with the nonhosted version.

Comment: I just played a couple of games without any trouble. (Nonhosted version)

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing the game almost daily since Halloween and haven't had any trouble getting games. Sometimes it takes longer for people to join, since I don't host a game, but then it plays just like it did on Halloween.

People are still playing it, no need to host a game. Just skip the tutorial and play.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is continuing to have problems playing, I was stuck at the "Waiting for Players" stage for days.  I just thought they took it offline.  Then after seeing here that other people were able to keep playing, I decided to use a VPN for Firefox to access the page from a different country (I'm in the US, I chose UK).  It worked like a charm, and I can play again.  Thought I'd share the fix, for those still having problems getting it to work.  Happy gaming :)

Answer (score 0):

The archive version is way too small but I found a screen version here:

https://www.google.com/logos/2018/halloween18/rc3/halloween18.html?hl=en